# C++/WinRT UWP FileOpenPicker missing

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to add a file selection button to a UWP C++/WinRT application, but I cannot seem to access the constructor following the same namespace as the C# examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers). I have linked the specific Visual Studio error I'm getting below in an image:

[image: Image Showing Error]

If I try to build it despite this error, I get the following output:

```
1>c:\users\albertdayn\source\repos\siemensirscannersoftware\scanview\mainpage.cpp(39): error C2039: 'FileOpenPicker': is not a member of 'winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt\winrt\impl\windows.storage.pickers.provider.2.h(18): note: see declaration of 'winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers'
1>c:\users\albertdayn\source\repos\siemensirscannersoftware\scanview\mainpage.cpp(39): error C2065: 'FileOpenPicker': undeclared identifier
```

Why can't I access the class? If I make a C# application I can run the example given in the link above just fine.

Comment: I have no problem with using ``FileOpenPicker`` in a C++/WinRT UWP project with VS 201 (15.9 update). You haven't shown your ``#include`` statements, so did you include the right headers?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Wow, how silly of me, thank you so much. I didn't realize that other C++/WinRT UWP classes were coming from "pch.h". After including `#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>` it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# and with C++/CX, references are automatically found and pulled into the modules upon first use.

For C++/WinRT, you need to explicitly include the correct header. In this case:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>
```

Comment: _For C++/WinRT, you need to explicitly include the correct header._ -> This is true for all of C++/WinRT, as it's a header-only library that relies on the inclusion of a couple libs being linked to, such as `WindowsApp.lib` for UWP stuff or `onecoreuap.lib` for C++/WinRT usage that doesn't need to work within the strict confines of a UWP app, such as messing with the registry or filesystem as a whole.